# What will happen if I powered a 24VDC device from a 27.8VDC power supply?

Tags: power, dc, backup

I have a device which has a power input from 12-24VDC Auto select and 250 mA load. I connected it with an online DC UPS which has an output of 27.8 VDC on grid mode and 24 VDC on Battery Mode. I tested it for 2 hours and it was working ok but I am worried if I connect it for more than 30 days then the device may fall, so can someone confirm that my doubt is correct?

---

The powered device is a class-1 laser device which even tells the input voltage and current when interface with its PC application. But it is not giving any warning about voltage increase. Also its an outdoor type with +70 Deg Celsius temperature rating. Moreover, I think it surly has a DC regulator circuit. What do you think?

[Sensor manual](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/optex-europe/sensor-downloads/Intrusion-Detection/Manuals/optex-fiber-synsys-fd340-series-manual-en.pdf)

[UPS datasheet](https://en.tps-elektronik.com/produkte/produktbeschreibung/tps300-upa24/339)

---

Thanks to all for the useful comments/suggestions.

i decided to use linear IC regulator to solve the issue.

Comment: What exactly is the device? A manufacturer name and model number, and perhaps a link to the datasheet, could be helpful.

Comment: Please share the device details

Comment: Why 30 days, it could fail at 23...

Comment: I suppose that that MA doesn't mean "MegaAmpere", but it is mA.

Comment: "12/24V auto select" suggests that the device was designed to handle installation in vehicles with nominal 12V or 24V electrical systems. Such electrical systems typically sit at 14.4V or 28.8V when charging, and devices intended for such applications are designed to handle that (and more!). You're probably OK as-is, but the only one who can say for sure is the manufacturer.

Comment: @DaveTweed, it is not a product intended for vehicles. It is a security product for home or business or whatever. It may be that they designed it for lead acid battery powering, and they are just saying "12-24V" as kind of shorthand. But I don't see how we can be sure. I would think the manufacturer would be able to answer that question, though. OP should definitely ask.

Comment: You should call or email the manufacturer and just ask them if you can connect it to two lead acid batteries.

Answer (score 4):

You are exceeding maximum ratings. That’s never a good idea unless you know the details of the design.

The maximum ratings were put in place by an engineer, and that engineer made her own choices regarding how conservative she wanted to be.

If you are unlucky, those extra 3.5 volts are internally multiplied by a large factor that puts components way out of their maximum ratings. This would mean your device will have a few minutes to live.

Maybe those extra 3.5V only puts components beyond their maximum ratings if certain load conditions arise. This would mean your device could fail at that random point.

Maybe you are very lucky and the designer was particularly conservative, and that 24V maximum rating is actually 40V so you would never have a problem.

However, there are components such as capacitors, whose overall life is reduced at higher voltages. If this is a 1yr reduction in a 100-year intended lifetime, or a 23 month reduction in a 2-year lifetime is completely up to the designer.

In consumer electronics it is rather common for parts to be as cheap as possible. Longer lifetimes imply higher costs, and that is also engineered. That 24V maximum might have been explicitly designed for a lifetime of 24 months at a 10% failure rate thus providing a conservative margin on a 1yr warranty.

---

Without any further information, it is not worth the risk. It only consumes 200mA maximum. Place a 5V 2W zener diode in series with it and call it a day.

If that solution seems silly, and you have already scoured through the manual trying to figure it out, your only rational option is to call the manufacturer and find out what are the actual design constraints on that specific parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell what will happen to the device unless you know how it's made at a circuit level. 
It could run without issues forever, it could just work for a limited amount of time and then stop, it could also break if you turn it off and turn it on again.

The manual exists for a reason and you should always follow the instructions.

I can make you an example: let's say that the designer decided to use a 27V zener (or TVS) to protect the device power input. If you power the device with 24V there's no problem, but if you use 27V or more the zener turns on and starts conducting potentially causing your device to fail.

If you are just a user and you don't know the circuits inside the device, stick to the indications on the manual.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I only know that the device is an expensive and high MTBF device. I am seriously thinking to limit the voltage to 24 VDC so kindly advise how can I do that?

Comment: Well, I know it's a dumb answer but, why can't you just buy a 12 to 24V power supply?
However, you could use any kind of voltage regulator that can take your UPS output voltage as an input voltage and take it down to 24V or less, and of course it should be capable to deliver at least 250mA. You could go for a linear voltage regulator or a SMPS, it's up to you, there are a lot of solutions available.

Comment: search for DC-DC converter, plenty of options there (including DIN rail type mounting).  Can't offer much more as we have no idea of power requirements, etc.  One piece of advice is to run the device at a lower voltage than 24V so that there is some headroom for the converter when running off the 24VDC mode.  You mentioned it can run from 12VDC-24VDC so again, lots of options.

Comment: @AmjadAli A small DC-DC step-down converter module can bring that 27.8V to 24V with ease. The problem is that they don't work if the input comes too close to the output (i.e. if that 27.8V decreases to, say, 24.5V). If that could happen you should use a buck-boost DC-DC converter, which is slightly more expensive.